# Plot to figures without bringing them into foreground

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
figure;
ax1 = axes;
figure;
ax2 = axes;
x = 0; y = 0;
while ishandle(ax1) && ishandle(ax2)
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
      figure(1)
      scatter(x,y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'red')
      hold on
      figure(2)
      scatter(x,y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'blue')
      hold on
  end
```

In my script I have multiple figures, which are going to be updated in a loop. The figures have to be displayed, while the script is running. Unfortunately the currently updated figure is always popping in the foreground, which makes it impossible to monitor a certain figure. I understand that the calling of `figure(1)` and `figure(2)` causes this behaviour, but I how can I plot to these figures, without bringing the window into foreground?

Comment: You could try `scatter(ax1, x,y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'red')` to specify the axes that should be used and not call `figure` at all.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. Works perfectly, thank you! I just stumbled upon `set(0,'CurrentFigure',<handle of figure>)`, but your idea may be even better.

Comment: @mikkola you should make that an answer, it is the way to go.

Comment: A better way is to update the `xdata` and `ydata` properties of the line. `h=plot(0,0,...)`, then inside the loop `h.xdata = [h.xdata,x]` and similarly for y. This is the fastest way to do it, and will use less memory if you have many points to plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mikkola suggested in a comment, you can specify to which axes `scatter` or `plot` add data points. However, there is a better method: create a single line object, and update its `xdata` and `ydata` properties. This is both faster and more memory efficient. Your code would become:

```
x = 0; y = 0;
figure;
h1 = plot(x,y,'ro');
figure;
h2 = plot(x,y,'bo');
while ishandle(h1) && ishandle(h2)
   x = x + 1;
   y = y + 1;
   h1.XData(end+1) = x;
   h1.YData(end+1) = y;
   h2.XData(end+1) = x;
   h2.YData(end+1) = y;
   drawnow
   pause(0.1)
end
```

I keep a set of rules of thumb for when working with MATLAB handle graphics. These are relevant to this question:

- Use `figure` only to create a new figure, or to bring an existing figure to the front (which you want to avoid in general, but sometimes is necessary).
- Always specify with which figure or axes you want to work, by keeping and using their handles. I never rely on `gcf` or `gca` (not explicitly nor implicitly). Using the current figure is useful when typing on the command line, but in a script or a function there is the real danger than someone clicks randomly on windows while the function is executing. Creating a window then writing to `gcf` could end up writing to a different figure (really, I click on random things all the time).
- Don't create more objects than necessary. Creating a new `line` object for every point you plot is wasteful.

Note also that `plot(...'o')` is equivalent to `scatter(...)` unless you specify a different color or size for each point. But using the dot size or color to specify additional information is not a good way to convey that information. Read [Tufte's "The visual display of quantitative information"](https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi) if you're interested in learning about effective communication through graphs.

Comment: Nice answer! Only one clarification - `plot(... 'o')` is not exactly like `scatter`, they assume different input. `plot` lets you enter several series of data in one call (as columns in a matrix) while `scatter` takes only one series at a time.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part can be found in the part of the [documentation of `scatter`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) that includes the input `ax`:

> `scatter(ax,___)` plots into the axes specified by `ax` instead of into
>   the current axes.

This allows the user to specify an axis handle pointing to which axes should be used for drawing the scatter plot. Thus if you skip using `figure` in your code and use the `ax` input instead, you avoid the "bring to front" behavior associated with `figure`.

You can modify your code as follows:

```
figure;
ax1 = axes;
figure;
ax2 = axes;
x = 0; y = 0;
while ishandle(ax1) && ishandle(ax2)
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
    scatter(ax1, x,y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'red')
    hold on
    scatter(ax2, x,y, 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'blue')
    hold on
end
```